# Update relationship property when using timestamp() as value

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have this code, which is great, but as you will see it adds a new relationship with every single view of the item.

```
return client.Cypher
            .Match("(p:Person)", "(s:Store)")
            .Where((Person p) => p.Email == username)
            .AndWhere((Store s) => s.Name == store)
            .Merge("(product:Product { pId: {pId} })")
            .OnCreate()
            .Set("product = {newProduct}")
            .WithParams(new
            {
                pId = newProduct.pId,
                newProduct
            })
            .CreateUnique("product-[:STOCK_FROM]->s")
            .CreateUnique("(p)-[b:BROWSED{timestamp:timestamp()}]->(s)")
            .CreateUnique("(p)-[v:VIEWED{timestamp:timestamp()}]->(product)")
            .Return<Product>("product").Results.ToList();
```

Now ideally I would like to add a second attribute called total, which would be an int. This attribute would be incremented with each visit and the timestamp updated as a 'lastviewed', like:

```
            .Create("(p)-[b:BROWSED{lastviewed:timestamp(),total:1}]->(s)")
            .Create("(p)-[v:VIEWED{lastviewed:timestamp(),total:1}]->
```

But I am not sure of 2 things...
 1. How to query for if the relationship already exists, I think it's going to be something like this:

```
.Match("(p:Person)-[:BROWSED]-(product)")
            .Where((Person p) => p.Email == username)
```

But I get stuck with an error about needing to use .With() if I run this after the .OnCreate, and this got me in a mess, but I digress..

2. Once queried, how to I increment the data value of the total attribute?

The problem being that I see answers in here from different versions of the client, and different versions of Neo4j, I am on 2.2.3 with the latest client (downloaded today).

Someone please help! :)

Couldn't fit this in the comments so I will update here:

```
return client.Cypher
            .Match("(p:Person)", "(s:Store)")
            .Where((Person p) => p.Email == username)
            .AndWhere((Store s) => s.SearchIndex == store)
            .Merge("(product:Product { ASIN: {ASIN} })")
            .OnCreate()
            .Set("product = {newProduct}")
            .WithParams(new
            {
                ASIN = newProduct.ASIN,
                newProduct
            })
            .CreateUnique("product-[:STOCK_FROM]->s")
            .Merge("(p)-[b:BROWSED]->(s)")
            .OnCreate()
            .Set("b.lastviewed=timestamp(), b.total=1")
            .OnMatch()
            .Set("b.lastviewed=timestamp(), b.total=b.total+1")
            .Return<Product>("product").Results.ToList();
```

Perfect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `MERGE` with `ON CREATE SET` and `ON MATCH SET``

```
MERGE (p)-[b:BROWSED]->(s)
ON CREATE SET b.total = 1
ON MATCH SET b.lastviewed=timestamp(), b.total=b.total+1
```

Not sure how good the MERGE support is in Neo4jClient

Or if you want to stay with CREATE

```
CREATE UNIQUE (p)-[b:BROWSED]->(s)
SET b.total = coalesce(b.total,1)+1, b.lastviewed=timestamp()
```